# i cant upload sql file that have size 24000 kb

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I can't import an sql file to phpmyadmin that have size 24000kb while the system said max size is 20000kb. I have edited php.ini in folder php. I've changed upload_max_filesize = 750M and post_max_size = 750M, but I still can't upload file that have size 24000 kb.

I use xampp v.5.6.12

Please help me to fix it!

Comment: Check out- http://stackoverflow.com/a/23548115/3681882

Comment: im so thankful but i have already read the whole of it. and still i cant get it fix. i use windows 8.1 pro anyway

Comment: Then I would recommend re-installing xampp. Come back with your results (and some screenshots if possible).

Comment: @ErikMega After you changed the limits, did you restart Apache? And if so, does phpMyAdmin still show that the max is 20000 KB?

Comment: hey guys, tnx for your help anyway. i have reinstall xampp then edit file php.ini
well its done. thank you anyway

Comment: Since the problem was solved by reinstalling and therefore the root cause remains unsolved with no chance to find a proper answer, I suggest that you close this question.

Answer (score 0):

1.16 I cannot upload big dump files (memory, HTTP or timeout problems).
Starting with version 2.7.0, the import engine has been re–written and these problems should not occur. If possible, upgrade your phpMyAdmin to the latest version to take advantage of the new import features.

The first things to check (or ask your host provider to check) are the values of `max_execution_time`, `upload_max_filesize`, `memory_limit` and `post_max_size` in the `php.ini` configuration file. All of these three settings limit the maximum size of data that can be submitted and handled by PHP. Please note that `post_max_size` needs to be larger than `upload_max_filesize`. There exist several workarounds if your upload is too big or your hosting provider is unwilling to change the settings:

Look at the `$cfg['UploadDir']` feature. This allows one to upload a file to the server via scp, ftp, or your favorite file transfer method. PhpMyAdmin is then able to import the files from the temporary directory. More information is available in the Configuration of this document.

Using a utility (such as `BigDump`) to split the files before uploading. We cannot support this or any third party applications, but are aware of users having success with it.

If you have shell (command line) access, use MySQL to import the files directly. You can do this by issuing the “source” command from within MySQL:

`source filename.sql;`