# Out of memory even with php.ini updated

Tags: php, linux, out-of-memory, vps

I have a VPS server ( with Apache ) using WHM (PHP Configuration Editor). I edited php.ini with this:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

max_execution_time = 3000
max_input_time = 6000
memory_limit = 3000M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
post_max_size =  1024M
```

After update and restarting its showing the updated limit but i am still getting this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 51118080) (tried to allocate 14588 bytes) in /

PhpmyAdmin > Import is showing

> (Max: 50MiB)

my public_html folder does not have any php.ini file.

Comment: Take a look at your `upload_max_filesize`, and `post_max_size` values.

Comment: first check which php.ini file the apache is using for php and then edit that file.

Comment: @Matt sorry i have to forgot mention it, i have already updated "upload_max_filesize, and post_max_size" . but same issue

Comment: Try modifying the options within `Main >> Server Configuration >> Tweak Settings` that say `PHP Max Post Size for cPanel PHP` and `PHP Max Upload Size for cPanel PHP`

Comment: your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707822/how-to-increase-import-size-limit-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: It'd be helpful to know **what you're trying to do**, and not simply 'PHP runs out of memory, that is all'.

Comment: @cybermonkey    

what you're trying to do > I am trying to resize image. and it was working fine on old server. i have just move my web into this new server and i am getting this error on this function  >>


$image = call_user_func('imagecreatefrom'.$types[$size[2]], $url);

Comment: When running command "php -i | grep memory_limit" inside Your Linux server, then what does it show?

Comment: @R.P  

"php -i | grep memory_limit"  > it's showing >  memory_limit => 1024M => 1024M

recently i have update 3000M to 1024M into php.ini

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding php "Out of memory" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118927/understanding-php-out-of-memory-error)

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara no, its different

Comment: It might be that somewhere in code, new memory_limit is set and that gets full very fast. Tried to put ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); just before the function that causes this problem. Also You can search for memory_limit inside Your code.

Comment: @R.P already done, but not working.

Comment: Solution :

WHM >  Service Configuration » Apache Configuration » Memory Usage Restrictions : 

here disable "RLimitMEM Settings" and save.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
WHM >  Service Configuration » Apache Configuration » Memory Usage Restrictions :
```

here disable "RLimitMEM Settings"  and save.